# How to convert CRUD status change log table into table with date and entity column?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

There's a change log table which tracks entities (parent/child) and their status (new/existing/deleted):

```
| timestamp              | parent | child | status   |
| ---------------------- | ------ | ----- | -------- |
| 2022-06-10 19:10:25-07 | p1     | c1    | new      |
| 2022-06-12 19:10:25-07 | p1     | c1    | existing |
| 2022-06-14 19:10:25-07 | p1     | c1    | deleted  |
| 2022-06-10 19:10:25-07 | p2     | c1    | new      |
| 2022-06-12 19:10:25-07 | p2     | c1    | deleted  |
```

When a `child` entity is of status `new` it means it was created, when the status is `existing` it means `child` keeps existing, when the status is `deleted` it means `child` is no longer relevant. Each row in the table above is generated by a manual job so there's no guarantee the job will run regularly. This means that rows with `existing` status are optional while `new` and `deleted` will appear for sure for each combination of `parent`/`child`.

I want to convert the table into the following structure:

```
| date       | parent | child |
| ---------- | ------ | ----- |
| 2022-06-10 | p1     | c1    |
| 2022-06-11 | p1     | c1    |
| 2022-06-12 | p1     | c1    |
| 2022-06-13 | p1     | c1    |
| 2022-06-10 | p2     | c1    |
| 2022-06-11 | p2     | c1    |
| 2022-06-10 | p2     | c1    |
```

where each date contains the rows with active `parent`/`child` entities for that date.

It’s important to point out that

1. The same combination of parent/child can be created/deleted multiple times.
2. The result table should be run from the perspective of the current date. That is if there's a `new` event for some parent/child combination on `2022-06-12 19:10:25-07` and there were not deleted events and today is August 8, 2023 then there should be a row for that combination on each day up to (and including) August 8, 2023. For example log table:

```
| timestamp              | parent | child | status   |
| ---------------------- | ------ | ----- | -------- |
| 2022-06-12 19:10:25-07 | p1     | c1    | new      |
```

should result in

```
| date       | parent | child |
| ---------- | ------ | ----- |
| 2022-06-12 | p1     | c1    |
| 2022-06-13 | p1     | c1    |
| 2022-06-14 | p1     | c1    |
.
.
.
| 2023-08-08 | p1     | c1    | (<= today's date)
```

3. If for some parent/child combination there's just a deleted event then that parent/child combination should be reflected on the days before the date of the deleted event. For example, we can define that the timeframe is last 30 days so the parent/child combination should appear on the days before and including the date of deleted event and after `current_date()-30` days. For example, if today is Aug 8 and the log table is as follows:

```
| timestamp              | parent | child | status   |
| ---------------------- | ------ | ----- | -------- |
| 2022-07-11 19:10:25-07 | p1     | c1    | deleted  |
```

then the expected result table should be:

```
| date       | parent | child |
| ---------- | ------ | ----- |
| 2022-07-08 | p1     | c1    |
| 2022-07-09 | p1     | c1    |
| 2022-07-10 | p1     | c1    |
| 2022-07-11 | p1     | c1    |
```

A generic SQL solution would be great but if it's not possible then Spark SQL would also be ok.

Comment: can you please explain more on `date` column from your expected output ? if status is delete , do you want that date to be in your expected results ?

Comment: If for some combination of parent /child in change log table the status is delete it means that  for that date parent/child should not appear.

Comment: ok, I have added solution based on my understanding from your question. please check and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the Spark SQL below

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM input").show(false)
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+
|child|parent|status  |timestamp           |
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+
|c1   |p1    |new     |2023-08-01T12:00:00Z|
|c1   |p1    |existing|2023-08-01T13:00:00Z|
|c1   |p1    |existing|2023-08-05T13:00:00Z|

|c2   |p2    |new     |2023-08-01T12:00:00Z|
|c2   |p2    |existing|2023-08-01T13:00:00Z|
|c2   |p2    |deleted |2023-08-05T13:00:00Z|

|c3   |p3    |new     |2023-08-01T08:00:00Z|
|c3   |p3    |existing|2023-08-01T13:00:00Z|
|c3   |p3    |deleted |2023-08-01T14:00:00Z|
|c3   |p3    |new     |2023-08-01T15:00:00Z|

|c4   |p4    |new     |2023-08-01T08:00:00Z|

|c1   |p5    |new     |2023-08-08T08:00:00Z|

|c6   |p6    |new     |2023-08-01T12:00:00Z|
|c6   |p6    |existing|2023-08-01T13:00:00Z|
|c6   |p6    |existing|2023-08-05T13:00:00Z|
+-----+------+--------+--------------------+
```

```
spark.sql("""WITH input AS (
        SELECT
            CAST(timestamp AS DATE) AS dt, 
            parent,
            child,
            status,
            cast(MAX(timestamp) OVER(PARTITION BY parent, child) AS DATE) as max_ts,
            CASE WHEN LEAD(CAST(timestamp AS DATE), 1) OVER(PARTITION BY parent, child order by timestamp desc) IS NULL 
                 THEN CAST(timestamp AS DATE) 
                 ELSE LEAD(CAST(timestamp AS DATE), 1) OVER(PARTITION BY parent, child order by timestamp desc) 
            END as min_ts,
            row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY parent, child order by timestamp desc) as row_number
        FROM curd_data
    ),
    transformed_input AS (
        SELECT 
            dt,
            parent,
            child,
            max_ts,
            min_ts,
            row_number,
            CASE WHEN dt == max_ts AND (status == 'existing' OR status == 'new') THEN datediff(current_date, min_ts)
                 WHEN dt == max_ts AND status == 'deleted'  THEN datediff(date_sub(max_ts, 1), min_ts)
            END AS new_date_diff ,
            transform(
                sequence(
                        0,
                        CASE WHEN dt == max_ts AND (status == 'existing' OR status == 'new')
                            THEN datediff(current_date, min_ts) 
                        WHEN dt == max_ts AND status == 'deleted'
                            THEN datediff(date_sub(max_ts, 1), min_ts)                        
                        END
                ),
                sid -> date_add(min_ts, sid)                              
            ) as dates 
        FROM input WHERE row_number = 1
    ) 
    SELECT 
        distinct
        explode_outer(dates) AS date,
        parent,
        child
    FROM 
    transformed_input
    """).show(100, false)
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+----------+------+-----+
|date      |parent|child|
+----------+------+-----+
|2023-08-01|p1    |c1   |
|2023-08-02|p1    |c1   |
|2023-08-03|p1    |c1   |
|2023-08-04|p1    |c1   |
|2023-08-05|p1    |c1   |
|2023-08-06|p1    |c1   |
|2023-08-07|p1    |c1   |
|2023-08-08|p1    |c1   |

|2023-08-01|p2    |c2   |
|2023-08-02|p2    |c2   |
|2023-08-03|p2    |c2   |
|2023-08-04|p2    |c2   | 

|2023-08-01|p3    |c3   | 
|2023-08-02|p3    |c3   |
|2023-08-03|p3    |c3   |
|2023-08-04|p3    |c3   |
|2023-08-05|p3    |c3   |
|2023-08-06|p3    |c3   |
|2023-08-07|p3    |c3   |
|2023-08-08|p3    |c3   |

|2023-08-01|p4    |c4   |
|2023-08-02|p4    |c4   |
|2023-08-03|p4    |c4   |
|2023-08-04|p4    |c4   |
|2023-08-05|p4    |c4   |
|2023-08-06|p4    |c4   |
|2023-08-07|p4    |c4   |
|2023-08-08|p4    |c4   |

|2023-08-08|p5    |c1   |

|2023-08-01|p6    |c6   |
|2023-08-02|p6    |c6   |
|2023-08-03|p6    |c6   |
|2023-08-04|p6    |c6   |
|2023-08-05|p6    |c6   |
|2023-08-06|p6    |c6   |
|2023-08-07|p6    |c6   |
|2023-08-08|p6    |c6   |

+----------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't think Spark `dateadd` but rather `date_add`. Also when running the query for parent/child combination with status `new` on `2023-07-01T12:00:00Z` and the last status `existing` on `2023-07-05T13:00:00Z` I don't get a row in the result table for `2023-07-05`

Comment: Ok, I will check

Comment: I found at least 2 more scenarios when the query doesn't produce correct results, documented them here: https://gist.github.com/yossisp/a268e60c4ed2a08a001be3fabaa6d1af#file-test_sql1-py

Comment: Thanks for putting in github. Can you please tell me what data has to show when all status is in same day like below. ```|c3   |p3    |new     |2023-07-01T08:00:00Z|
|c3   |p3    |existing|2023-07-01T13:00:00Z|
|c3   |p3    |deleted |2023-07-01T14:00:00Z|
|c3   |p3    |new     |2023-07-01T15:00:00Z|
```

Comment: I have updated logic for all scenarios except above scenario.. if you can tell what is output of above scenario I will update the logic.

Comment: Regarding the example from your comment above the output should be `2023-07-01|c3|p3` even if the combination was deleted it still existed in that day. One of the examples regarding this in my gist was incorrect, I removed it from the gist.

Comment: ok, I have added output & input in your gist - https://gist.github.com/yossisp/a268e60c4ed2a08a001be3fabaa6d1af#file-test_sql1-py check & let me know

Comment: I probably should've mentioned this explicitly in the OP but the result table is always from the perspective of the current date. So in the this example (https://gist.github.com/yossisp/a268e60c4ed2a08a001be3fabaa6d1af#file-test_sql1-py-L85) even if new combinations happened on `2023-07-01` and there were no deleted events then those combinations need to appear up to the current date (added output example https://gist.github.com/yossisp/a268e60c4ed2a08a001be3fabaa6d1af#file-test_sql1-py-L143)

Comment: I didn't get you .. can you give me some examples or update your question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254850/discussion-between-yos-and-srinivas).

Comment: Updated the OP and found another incorrect result: https://gist.github.com/yossisp/a268e60c4ed2a08a001be3fabaa6d1af#file-test_sql1-py-L234

Comment: updated code with latest logic.

Comment: Unfirtunately this SQL doesnt produce correct results for a number of edge cases. It’d be great if you could fix the SQL otherwise it’ll just be misleading to readers

Comment: Please create new question with all your possible edge cases and expected solutions.. will fix it.

Comment: There're no new edge cases than the ones described in the OP. Try for example for a combination which gets created and deleted repeatedly

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
-- First, create a table that marks the beginning and end of each active period for each parent/child combination
changes AS (
  SELECT 
    parent,
    child,
    CASE 
      WHEN status = 'new' THEN timestamp 
      WHEN LAG(status) OVER (PARTITION BY parent, child ORDER BY timestamp) = 'new' AND status = 'deleted' THEN timestamp 
    END as active_period,
    status
  FROM 
    log_table 
  WHERE 
    status IN ('new', 'deleted')
),
-- Then, create a table that matches each 'new' record with the subsequent 'deleted' record for each parent/child combination
matched_periods AS (
  SELECT 
    parent,
    child,
    MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'new' THEN active_period END) as start_date,
    MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'deleted' THEN active_period END) as end_date
  FROM 
    changes
  GROUP BY 
    parent,
    child,
    FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent, child ORDER BY active_period) - 1) / 2)
),
-- Finally, create a table that lists each date within each active period for each parent/child combination
final_table AS (
  SELECT
    DATE(EXPLODE(SEQUENCE(TO_DATE(start_date), TO_DATE(end_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) AS date,
    parent,
    child
  FROM
    matched_periods
)
SELECT * FROM final_table ORDER BY date, parent, child;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When I run the query it results in `AnalysisException: Generators are not supported when it's nested in expressions, but got: DATE(explode(sequence(to_date(start_date), to_date(end_date), INTERVAL '1' DAY)))` error, you didn't get the error?

Comment: I'm getting a lot of `AnalysisException`s what Spark version were you using? I'm using pyspark 3.3.0.

Comment: I re-worked your query to pass all the exceptions I got when running, it doesn't product the correct results at least for one scenario: https://gist.github.com/yossisp/7ce90216e61a548198489450a99052fa